# Form1.Hide vs Form1.Close

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Which works better with opening a new form and closing an old one, `form1.hide` or `form1.close`?

On a buttonClick handler on Form1 I wrote:

```
Form1.Hide;
Form2.Show;
```

And then it gets stuck in a debugging session. (Only happened once -_-)

Then when I use

```
Form1.close;
Form2.Show;
```

All the forms close. Whats the difference between the two? (Other than `.close` actually closing everything xD)

Comment: `ExecuterHitmanDude` is a `string`. The `and` operator operates on booleans and returns a boolean. What are you trying to do with that `ExecuterHitmanDude := (Form1.Hide) and (Form2.show)` expression?

Comment: @mbratch Your right, I don't exactly know where my mind was, thanks for that.

Comment: What's the purpose behind saving the return value of `Hide` with `ExecuterHitmanDude := Form1.Hide`? I believe the `Hide` method is a `procedure`, not a `function`, so it has no return value.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to remove the "another note" portion. It has nothing to do with the topic at hand. Instead, ask it as a separate question. Asking it here in *this* question just distracts from the main issue, and you'll get answers that are harder to understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Hide` simply sets Visible to false.

Close fires `OnCloseQuery` and `OnClose` events. If the form in question is the application's main form, the application will terminate. Depending on `CloseAction`  the form will either Hide (`CloseAction = caHide`), Minimise (`CloseAction = caMinimize`) or free itself (`CloseAction = caFree`)

Your second question is unclear as to what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Edited the question. For instance making a shortcut to `ExecuterHitmanDude := Form1.Hide; Form2.Show;` Kind of thing, is that possible? So instead of having to say `Form1.Hide; form2.show;` you can just say `ExecuterHitmanDude` ?

Comment: Lets say I have a button to go the the next form, such as a "Proceed", then I want a "Back" button. So for the proceed ButtonClick, it would close/hide the first form and open the second, making the code look like `Form1.Hide; form2.show;` and instead of that, I can just type `Executerblah` It was just a question of curiosity if it were possible.. I am a noob/beginner coder/programmer (as you can see).

Comment: I think you're describing a Procedure. I suggest you read the documentation  and start from there. http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Procedures_and_Functions